# ReactJS async, wait for results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and trying to understand it. Now I have a situation where I am loading information needed for rendering. But as it is asynchronous the component renders itself before the information is passed to it.

```
var info;

function getInfo() {
    //this will come from backend REST with Backbone which takes a bit
}

var InfoPage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {        
        getInfo()

        return (
            <div>info: {info}</div>            
        );
    }
});
```

Now the div will not show the info-value as it is not yet set in the render. So how can I have get render to wait for the info? Or how should this be solved?

The actual React.renderComponent is called from top level and that triggers all the subcomponents so I think I cannot force new render (and I shouldn't?).

Comment: You shouldn't have any backend calls in the *rendering* routine!

Answer (score 23):

You need to do something like below:

```
var InfoPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return {info: "loading ... "};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
     this.getInfo();
  },
  render: function() {        
    return (
        <div>info: {this.state.info}</div>            
    );
  },
  getInfo:function(){
     $.ajax({ url:"restapi/getInfo/whatever", .... }).success(function(res){
        this.setState({info:res});
     }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: How would one do this without using jQuery or jQuery.ajax()?

Comment: @ConAntonakos Why not using jQuery? If you really want to get rid of jQuery, you may want to check [this site](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: The use of ajax is irrelevant to the pattern that QusaiJouda is demonstrating here. You can use whatever method you want to fetch data. The point is to demonstrate the pattern of pre-populating state with temporary placeholder values.

Comment: If someone around these days, modern web dev would use fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 19):

### `ComponentDidMount` Lifecycle Method

According to the docs, `componentDidMount` is the component hook you should be using to do your ajax request:

> http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount
>
> **ComponentDidMount**
>
> Invoked immediately after rendering occurs... If you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks, set timers using setTimeout or setInterval, or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.

### Example

Using your example, the code might look like this:

```
var InfoPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { info: {} };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/info.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({info: data});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render: function() {        
    return (
      <div>info: {this.state.info}</div>            
    );
  }
});
```

### `getInitialState`

Above, we are using the `getInitialState` method to return an empty `info` object.  This allows our component to render, while we wait for the server to return with data.

Once `componentDidMount` executes, it will use `this.setState` to replace the empty `info` and the server data and re-`render` the component.

### Further reading

You can see this approach used in in the [Updating state](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state) section of the [React tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).

Comment: This offers a somewhat related best practice, but fails to answer the actual question. The OP wants to finish an async request BEFORE rendering is complete. What this is suggesting is to run any async method after rendering or to rerender after rendering the first time.