# How to make asynchronous calls inside a forEach() which depends on data from another asynchronous call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I am working with an API and want to make some calls from my React application. They are async calls nested inside a forEach(). I get all the promises and push them inside a promises array. Then use the axios.all() method as described by axios docs but when I push the results of these promises to the myData array I get an empty array.

Except axios.all(promises) method I tried nested then() calls on Promises but that just complicated everything. Here is my code:

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.to !== nextProps.to || this.props.from !== 
nextProps.from) {
  let promises = [];
  Axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/visits?from=${this.props.from}&to=${
      this.props.to
    }`
  ).then(res => {
    res.data.forEach(visit => {
      promises.push(
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/clients/${visit.clientId}`
        })
      );
    });
    Axios.all(promises).then(results => {
      results.forEach(res => {
        const clientProps = {
          name: res.data[0].name,
          lastname: res.data[0].lastname,
          mobile_number: res.data[0].mobile_number
        };
        myData.push(clientProps); // Here I am pushing the data to a global array
      });
this.setState({myData})
    });
  });
 }
}
```

When I run the code I expect the array "myData" to be filled with the data pushed from the API call but instead I get an empty array. Is there any way to get around this problem?

```
// I try to access data from this.state inside the render() method of my class component to generate a Table data with the name property.

 <td>{this.state.myData[index].name}</td>
```

Comment: You pushed data to myData but I guess you don't update the component. If you share other parts of application would be better.

Comment: pushing to `myData` will happen only after all the requests are made and resolved. It looks like you are trying to access it synchronously, which will be before it has been filled.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code: a loose closing brace after your second `get`.

Comment: Could you include the code where you access `myData` and find it to be empty?

Comment: @CenkÇetinkaya I update the component using this.setState({ myData}). I think the problem is inside my async calls.

Comment: @trincot ok I updated my code in my question

Comment: That explains it. You cannot know the result at the time the HTML is rendered. At that time the requests are still pending. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185029/reactjs-async-wait-for-results) how you can use `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: this.setState(() => ({myData})) did you try this?

Comment: @CenkÇetinkaya What is the difference between this.setState(() => ({myData})) and this.setState({myData})

Comment: This version is more convinient way when set state one after another."Due to the async nature of setState, it is not advisable to use this.state to get the previous state within setState. Instead, always rely on the above way. Both prevState and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this version is more handy.

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.to !== nextProps.to || this.props.from !== 
nextProps.from) {
  let promises = [];
  Axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/visits?from=${this.props.from}&to=${
      this.props.to
    }`
  ).then(res => {
    return Axios.all(res.data.map(visit => {
      return Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/clients/${visit.clientId}`)
    }))
  })
  .then(results => {
      return results.map(res => {
          return {
          name: res.data[0].name,
          lastname: res.data[0].lastname,
          mobile_number: res.data[0].mobile_number
        };
      });
    })
  .then(clientProps => {
    // then update state or dispatch an action
    this.setState(() => ({myData: clientProps}));
  });

}
}
```

Comment: @DavidPrifti this.setState(() => ({myData})) did you try this? Maybe?

Comment: An another thing is if you set initial state in constructor then it can overwrite as []

Comment: I am sorry for saying this didn't work. I was missing the parenthesis before the {myData} in this.setState(). After doing that it worked! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
getVisits(from, to) {
  return Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/visits?from=${from}&to=${to}`);
}

getClients(ids) {
  return Axios.all(ids.map(id => Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/clients/${id}`));
}

async getClientsOfVisits(from, to) {
  const response = await this.getVisits(from, to);
  const promises = await this.getClients(response.data.map(visit => visit.clientId)));

  return promises.map(res => res.data[0]);
}

componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  const { to, from } = this.props;
  const toChanged = to !== nextProps.to;
  const fromChanged = from !== nextProps.from;

  if (toChanged || fromChanged) {
    this.getClientsOfVisits(to, from).then(myData => {
      this.setState({ myData });
    })
  }
}
```